# Refer to previous line output in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Consider the following :

[image]

`%` refers to the previous output.

Is there a way to refer to the previous line`s output no matter what was the last output in time ?

What I am trying to avoid defining the output such as

```
 blah=Range[10]
```

**Edit :For belisarius,the Problem**

[image]

Save untitled 2. Close, Open Quit[] and then :

[image]

Comment: First: Variables (symbols) exist to persist long term results. Second: `Out[-n]` allows you to refer to a previous line counting upwards, and so does not suffer your `Save & Load` symptom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

See [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Out.html)

**Edit**

Another example

[image]

Comment: I tried, but then If I add a line above and rerun the all thing it goes wrong for those number have changed

Comment: @500 That is the way it works. It is intended to be used in drafts (quick and dirty calculations) only. Perhaps you could explain your requirement in more detail.

Comment: @500 I think I am missing something in your question. See the new example

Comment: @500 My parser throws a protection violation with your `I was capable a problem`

Comment: Sorry : please see the Edit. I am glad for once I was capable of "replicating" (was missing) problem while asking help on it :). Must your "parser throws a protection violation" threw my Parser in the wild asking for Google help !

Comment: Funny thing about `%`, it's immune to `;`!  So lots of `Table[..., {bigNumber}];` will indeed fill up memory through `Out` eventually, despite the `;` ...

Answer (score 2):

You could use **Insert > Output from Above**.  That will copy the entire output though, not the `%k` short-form.

Comment: I always forget that one. Nice!

Comment: Sorry, I don`t get it, in which form do I write  your "Output from above"?

Comment: @500 If I under stand your question -- it's a menu item.  (and has the keyboard shortcut shift-ctrl-l on Windows/Linux and shift-command-l on OS X.)